# Winform Application flickers on XP system

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, flicker

Hi I have a windows application (winform .net framework 4). The app is flickering alot on windows XP system. I added code:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return cp;
    }
}
```

The flickers were removed when I added above code. It worked fine on my development system which is **windows 7 32 bit** but On **Windows XP** the flickers has increased and also the background image is not loaded.

Is there any way by which flickers can be removed in all the windows OS?

Comment: Why don't you use SetStyle()?

Comment: Did you activate double buffered for all your forms and controls?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I am new to this, could be please provide a example of how to use SetStyle()

Comment: aush did in his answer (you have to do it in control's constructor after InitializeComponent). Do it only for the control that is flickering (the one you manually draw).

Comment: No I did not activate double Buffered. How do I activate it? and DO I need to activate it individually for each of the control on the form?

Comment: Do I need to do all the thing? setstyle, override createparams and doublebuffer for each of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is some information about Double Buffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b367a457(v=vs.110).aspx).  This is a built-in feature that is turned off by default.  In my experience it doesn't always help but it is worth trying.

To turn it on, open the designer and select the form and look in the Properties of the form.  Under the category 'Behavior' you will find the DoubleBuffered property.  Just set this to true.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may also try

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

Comment: Where this has to be set?

Comment: In the constructor of your control/form.

Comment: Both the solutions has to be implemented? i.e setstyle and overriding createParams? Or setStyles will do it?

Comment: Well, you better test it. Results may vary depending on what is actually happening on your forms.

Comment: the flicker is still not gone. however it has reduced. Now only form.show and form.close is causing flickering.